# DocuSign redirect url event documentation

Tags: docusignapi

I have searched StackOverflow and DocuSign documentation for a list of all redirect events, with only missing results.

(e.g https://developers.docusign.com/search/?q=signing_complete and https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/ do not have the list of events)

Does a list of these event exist anywhere? (signing_complete, decline, cancel, session_timeout...)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of values for the `event` query parameter is included with the [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient) documentation, but it is not easy to find.

The list is included with the documentation for the [returnUrl parameter](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/#schema__recipientviewrequest_returnurl).

### The `event` query parameter return values as of July, 2022

- **access_code_failed**: Recipient used incorrect access code.
- **cancel**: Recipient canceled the signing operation, possibly by using the Finish Later option.
- **decline**: Recipient declined to sign.
- **exception**: A system error occurred during the signing process.
- **fax_pending**: Recipient has a fax pending.
- **id_check_failed**: Recipient failed an ID check.
- **session_timeout**: The session timed out. An account can control this timeout by using the Signer Session Timeout option.
- **signing_complete**: The recipient completed the signing ceremony.
- **ttl_expired**: The Time To Live token for the envelope has expired. After being successfully invoked, these tokens expire after 5 minutes or if the envelope is voided.
- **viewing_complete**: The recipient completed viewing an envelope that is in a read-only/terminal state, such as completed, declined, or voided.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list in the [LoanCo Sample App](https://loanco.sampleapps.docusign.com/sign/return?event=signing_complete)